# meaning of select in xsl:call template

Tags: xml, xslt

This question may sound very basic but I am confused as to what exactly is purpose of 'SELECT ' in xsl:call Template

like Here I have a snippet

```
<xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
          <xsl:with-param name="string" select="//text()" />
```

so what does select does in the following snippet

Thanks

Comment: The `select` is part of `<xsl:with-param>` here. But it does what every `select` does in XSLT - it selects nodes. What is your actual question?

Comment: Hi Tomalak Thanks for the link ..Actually I am confused like when It will pass the parameter String to a template 'Tokenize' then actually what is going to get selected'//text()'(What does this simplify)

Comment: `//text()` selects all text nodes in the *entire input document*. This is probably not what you want, but this is what it does. Hint: use `.//text()` to select all text nodes in the *current node* (this is a list of nodes, not a string!). Use `normalize-space(.)` to select a string representation of the current node (this is an actual string).

Answer (score 0):

This is an example which might help you. Input XML:

```
<root>
<text>text1</text>
<text>text2</text>
<text>text3</text>
</root>
```

and XSLT being:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="//text()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$string">
        <xsl:element name="text{position()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output you get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <text1>text1</text1>
   <text2>text2</text2>
   <text3>text3</text3>
</root>
```

In the template, which matches "/", you are calling another template "tokenize".
The select statement "//text()" selects all the text() nodes in the whole document and these nodes are passed as parameter "string" to the "tokenize" template.
The template "tokenize" receives all these text nodes, loops on each, and create an element with the text() node's value.